# setw() and setfill() not working...what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++, formatting, number-formatting, cout, setw

what i am trying to do is print **double datatype** with **precision 2**,**setw(15)**,**fill spaces with _(underscore)** and with **prefix - or +**.for example if **number is 2006.008** **output** should be **_______+2006.01**

my code is :

```
 cin>>b;
if(b>0){
    cout<<setw(15)<<setfill('_');
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<"+"<<b<<endl;
}
else{
    cout<<setw(15)<<setfill('_');
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<"-"<<b<<endl;
}
```

output i am getting is :
______________+2006.01

**difference:** my output is getting 14 underscores

but in result there should be only 7 underscores

**what i tried?**

without prefix my answer is accurate because if i am adding prefix setw(15) is counting my prefix as 15th character and adding 14 underscores before it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The io-manipulators apply to single insertions to the stream. When you insert `"+"` into the stream, then the width of it is `1` and the remaining `14` are filled with `_` because of `setfill('_')`.

If you want io-manipulators to apply to concatenated strings you can concatenate the strings. I use a stringstream here, so you can apply `setprecision` and `fixed`:

```
if(b>0){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "+" << fixed << setprecision(2) << b;
    cout << setw(15) << setfill('_') << s.str() << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::showpos` instead of ouputting string literals `"+"` or `"-"`.

```
cout<<setw(15)<<setfill('_');
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<std::showpos<<b<<endl;
```

Otherwise `std::setw` sets the field width for the string literals `"+"` or `"-"`.